# Configure Oracle name resolution for procedures

Tags: oracle

I've got a procedure

```
shema_name.package_name.procedure_name
```

The software using database is written to call it like:

```
call package_name.procedure_name;
```

How do I configure the login software uses to access the database so that name resolution is performed correctly? Note that the login accessing database and the procedure definer are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- Create a synonym:

> create synonym package_name for schema_name.package_name

- use current_schema session parameter:

> ALTER SESSION set current_schema = schema_name

Comment: Will second option prevent me from using previous current_schema tables in a usual way?

Answer (score 2):

Make public synonyms to all objects referenced like this.

Or, if only one schema refers to them and you don't want to pollute public namespace - make synonyms only in that schema.

Comment: I'd avoid public synonyms where possible.

Comment: Me too. That's why I wrote the second line. But if he has three hundred different users using this schema - maybe making 1 set of public synonyms would be a better idea, then 300 copies of them. As for `set current_schema` approach - this means you should have an access to source code of software in question, which, I feel, he has not.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe a login trigger based on the application name could perform an "alter session"

Comment: Login trigger can lead to lot's of problems especially if from some reason the trigger starts to fail.